# Got lower offer than initially negotiated. Should I refuse?

Tags: job-search, salary

I'm an engineering graduate looking for job opportunities while at the same time I'm on a internship in a big company. Recently, I received an offer of full-time job with higher pay than currently. Motivated by raise in salary, I accepted the offer and gave a notice to my employer. I did not receive any written offer: In country where I live, there is no possibility of signing a contract before giving a notice. There is something called "letter of intent" which can be used as legal just-in-case document but no employer bothers with it for entry-level jobs.

Fast forward to the last day of my job, I received a call from the recruiter that they need to change the offer to lower salary, which is well below what was proposed before and almost exactly how much I'm paid on my internship.

With this information, I'm really stuck on what to do. Firstly, this behaviour looks to me as a extremely bad sign on my soon-to-be employer. Secondly, if I knew about the final offer in advance, I probably would never have given a notice in my current job.

If I choose to keep the new job, how can I go about negotiating back toward the original offer? If I refuse the new job, what options should I be aware of?

Comment: How can they change the salary? Did you signed some contract? Do you have something to claim that they agreed to pay you that? ... it is better to actually sign a contract or agreement *before* giving your notice, otherwise these things can happen.

Comment: @DarkCygnus It was just a verbal agreement on contract terms and I have no real (written) evidence of that. In my country of residence, there is no possibility of signing a contract before giving a notice. There is something called "letter of intent" which can prevent such situations but noone does has this on entry-level jobs. The question is more about if I should stay away from this employer instantly or maybe make deals with the devil.

Comment: I see. If you should or not is ultimately your choice (and asking that is off topic here). Personally, this seems fishy to me; I would seriously reconsider working there, as they actually went back on their word here (too bad you don't have even an email with the initial offer). Good luck with that, you probably would be better looking for job elsewhere anyways.

Comment: "Take the 2nd job, get a 3rd job as early as possible, then disappear from 2nd job without notice." is how I would have handled it. In future,  always get things in writing,  even if it means an email.

Comment: I'm not certain this is off topic. This is unfortunately not a rare occurrence and the details seem generic enough to apply to those situations yet concise enough to give a proper response.

Comment: @psaxton I've just added that background info

Comment: @Joe Strazzere. In general, it's hard to get a full-time job with that salary level. It's much easier to get an internship but with 20-30% lower money. The explanation on change of offer was "we made a mistake on how much money the actual people earn on that position". But I don't believe it because it sounds silly - they don't even know how much they pay for that job?

Comment: @QuicheLorraine consider adding a country or location tag to your question, so it gives more context on the possible solutions here.

Comment: @psaxton Common or not, it is asking us to make the decision, which [is not really something we can do](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693#2695). There may be an on topic question down there somewhere, but the question will need to be edited.

Comment: I am not sure it matters whether the root cause is incompetence or malice. Similar behavior, however caused, could make for an unpleasant job experience.

Comment: Why can you not sign a contract before giving notice ? and did you not get an offer letter with a stated salary ?

Comment: @Neuromancer As stated in original post, there is no possibility of signing a contract before you are on notice in my country. I didn't get any offer letter. The recruiter called me with this information. Now I know that I should at least have asked for email confirmation, but it's beyond repair now.

Comment: @QuicheLorraine I asked  "Why is there no possibility  of signing a contract" which country do you live in that has a legal system that broken?

Comment: First, talk to your old employer. If they were sad to see you leaving, they might be happy to get you back. Better yet, if you haven't left yet, you might convince them to forget about you giving notice. Depends on the employer, but worth a try. Then start looking for a job elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is bad juju.

If you need the income try to get your current employer to keep you on.

If your culture allows incomplete employment history, start at the new job only long enough to find a different (even if not better) income source. Keep your time at the new job short enough you can leave it entirely out of your resume/cv as if you were unemployed for the duration. Remember you may give them the same courtesy they gave you in changing the offer in the eleventh hour. Don't feel bad about leaving with 0 day notice.

Immediately contact whatever government employment ministries are available to you and report the situation. Be sure to provide copies of any supporting documentation. You may have certain legal rights.

Avoid any further dealings with that company as well as the recruiters company like the plague. If you hear of anyone else entertaining either company be certain to relate your experiences to them.

Comment: https://youtu.be/1EO7y3LBOrg